# Ubuntu DWM using beep as battery warning

Tags: sound, alsa

**Edit -- For those interested, I have solved the problem and clarified some of the code in my scripts in my second post below**

I am running a small script in .xinitrc that polls acpi for battery information. If it is below a certain then level beep is called as a warning.

However, it seems like beep is not audible unless I have played other audio before calling it. This is why I am calling mpv to play a short mp3 track on starting x. It is as if my soundcard is not activated on boot until I play something with audio.

My current problem is that it also cycles off after sleep until i play audio.

Below is my .xinitrc script. I am using alsamixer and running a minimal install of 16.04 with DWM as my window manager. Beep is installed from apt.

I would really appreciate a solution to make beep audible at all times - this might translate to keeping my soundcard active after a wake from hibernation. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Matthew

**.xinitrc**

```
xbacklight = 50 &

setxkbmap -option 'caps:ctrl_modifier'
xcape -e 'Caps_Lock=Escape'
setxkbmap -option 'caps:ctrl_modifier'
xcape -e 'Caps_Lock=Escape;Control_L=Escape;Control_R=Escape' 

amixer -q sset Master 75% &
amixer -q sset Beep 35% &

slstatus -d &
nm-applet &
./suckless/clipmenu/clipmenud &

modprobe pcspkr &
while true; do
    ./suckless/batt_warn
    sleep 15s
done &

mpv ./suckless/start.mp3 &
exec dwm
```

**batt_warn**

```
#!/bin/bash
BATT=$( acpi -b | sed 's/.*[charging|unknown], \([0-9]*\)%.*/\1/gi' )
STATUS=$( acpi -b | sed 's/.*: \([a-zA-Z]*\),.*/\1/gi' )
if ([ $BATT -le 5 ] && [ $STATUS == 'Discharging' ]); then
    beep && sleep 0.05
    beep && sleep 0.05
    beep && sleep 0.05
fi
```

Comment: As a workaround, you could  play your mp3  every x minutes from a crontab . There some tweak to play sound from a crontab , about setting the X session to use, but you will find it easily .

Comment: Thanks for your comment laugeo. I have found a workaround that doesn't need crontab, as it seems that waking from sleep was the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi everyone I thought I should post my solution as this is a problem many are likely to face when using a WM like dwm.

I have found a solution that plays a short mp3 in the background on boot as well as resume from sleep. This seems to have worked perfectly
 I also took advantage of the resume script to remap my custom keys as these are lost after sleep. 
Feel free to pm me if anyone needs help in the future.

-----------------------------------------------------------------

**.xinitrc**

Modprobe needed to enable system beep that is blacklisted on ubuntu.

Note: 
init is my executable initialisation script to be called on startx from .xinitrc and resume from 99Wake.sh

Note: 
batt_warn is my executable script to check the battery

```
slstatus -d &
nm-applet &
./suckless/clipmenu/clipmenud &

./suckless/init &

modprobe pcspkr &
while true; do
    ./suckless/batt_warn
    sleep 15s
done &

exec dwm
```

**init**

Sets caps as esc if pressed and as ctrl if used as leader 
Sets reasonable backlight and volume 
Uses mpv to play short mp3 clip start.mp3

```
#!/bin/bash
setxkbmap -option 'caps:ctrl_modifier'
xcape -e 'Caps_Lock=Escape'
setxkbmap -option 'caps:ctrl_modifier'
xcape -e 'Caps_Lock=Escape;Control_L=Escape;Control_R=Escape' 

xbacklight = 50 &
amixer -q sset Master 75% &
amixer -q sset Beep 35% &

cd ~ && mpv suckless/start.mp3 &
```

**batt_warn** 
Polls battery using acpi and plays beep if below 5% and discharging

```
#!/bin/bash
BATT=$( acpi -b | sed 's/.*[charging|unknown], \([0-9]*\)%.*/\1/gi' )
STATUS=$( acpi -b | sed 's/.*: \([a-zA-Z]*\),.*/\1/gi' )
if ([ $BATT -le 5 ] && [ $STATUS == 'Discharging' ]); then
    beep && sleep 0.05
    beep && sleep 0.05
    beep && sleep 0.05
fi
```

**99Wake.sh**

This file has been made executable with chmod +x 
And moved to the dir /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d\ 
Scripts in this dir are run on resume. Here I am calling init again. 
Note:
 As I am storing the script in my local users directory i had to add the sudo line but this was just done so .xinitrc and 99wake.sh could share the same init file rather than duplicating.

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
thaw|resume)
sudo -u matthew env DISPLAY=:0 zenity --info --text "do stuff on resume"
./home/matthew/suckless/init
;;
esac
```